# Is there an equivalent of Resteasy proxy client in Spring?

Tags: spring, rest

With [Resteasy](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.4.Final/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Client_Framework.html), it is possible to create REST clients only with an interface (a dynamic proxy is created for you so you don't have to provide an implementation of that interface yourself). Is there something similar in Spring? (A factory that would encapsulate a `RestOperations` and provide implementations based on an annotated interface and a base URI.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Data is going to implement this: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-475

Answer (score 0):

Yes Spring provide a class named [RestTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) that implement client RestOperations.

Comment: This is not was I am asking for. I want an dynamic implementation of an interface which models a REST API. You can find an example [here](http://kingsfleet.blogspot.be/2009/09/javalangreflectproxy-client-based-on.html)